# Behat + mink how to test jquery-ui autocomplete field?

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete, behat, mink

I'm using Behat to test a registration page.
This page contains a few fields with autocompletion.
User fills in some value in the field, page waits 500 milliseconds, makes an ajax-request and displays some options along with a relevant message (no items found / several items found / one item found).

I'm using a predefined step "I fill in *field* with *value*" (tried to use "I fill in *value* for *field*" instead).
Next step is custom, similar to one described in [documentation](http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html#defining-our-own-featurecontext) - I'm just waiting for message to appear and check that it has correct text.

But after filling the field Mink removes focus from it, causing *blur* event to be fired on the field.
Jquery-ui clears the field value in response to this *blur* event, so after 500 milliseconds field is empty and ajax request is aborted.

How can I fix this problem?

Behat v2.5.0
Mink v1.5.0
Mink-extension v1.3.3
Jquery-ui v1.8.21
Selenium v2.44.0

Comment: https://github.com/Behat/MinkSelenium2Driver/blob/v1.1.1/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/Selenium2Driver.php#L615

This is the reason of my troubles - mink generates change event on the field, so I guess the problem is in my js.

Answer (score 0):

Solution below is specific to my markup code but should be easily adapted to yours. You might need to modify it.

Assuming that selecting auto suggested option in textbox. Autosuggestion options appear as `<li>` elements after user’s key strokes. `<li>` element presents in the page however its content is empty at the beginning so there is nothing to be selected by behat. To solve the problem, non existing content between `<li>` tags is wrapped with `<label>` tag.

User types in this auto suggestion field:

```
<input name="brand" type="text" />
```

Where autosuggestion data appears:

```
<ul>
<li><label>{{ suggestion }}</label></li>
</ul>
```

**Gherkin:**

```
When I fill in "brand" with "S"
And I wait 1 seconds
Then I select autosuggestion option "Sula"
And I wait 1 seconds
......
```

**FeatureContext:**

```
/**
 * @Given /^I wait (\d+) seconds$/
 */
public function iWaitSeconds($seconds)
{
    sleep($seconds);
}

/**
 * @Then /^I select autosuggestion option "([^"]*)"$/
 *
 * @param $text Option to be selected from autosuggestion
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function selectAutosuggestionOption($text)
{
    $session = $this->getSession();
    $element = $session->getPage()->find(
        'xpath',
        $session->getSelectorsHandler()->selectorToXpath('xpath', '*//*[text()="'. $text .'"]')
    );

    if (null === $element) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Cannot find text: "%s"', $text));
    }

    $element->click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
My markup and steps are very similar, and the problem is inside the step 'When I fill in "brand" with "S"'.
When field is filled it loses focus, so no ajax-request is made and there is no point in waiting any number of seconds - no values are shown.

Comment: There is no loss of focus problem in my case and the example above waits for the response so the `wait` has to be in place but if you have a different way of doing things then you can still modify it as you wish.

Comment: My colleague doesn't have this problem on his computer also. I've tried to use the same selenium and firefox versions, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Scenario: I'm stuck
  Given I use jquery-ui-autocomplete
  And I can not test it with behat
  Then I trigger keyDown event like this:
  """
   /**
    * @When I select :entry after filling :value in :field
    */
   public function iFillInSelectInputWithAndSelect($entry, $value, $field)
   {
       $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
       $field = $this->fixStepArgument($field);
       $value = $this->fixStepArgument($value);
       $page->fillField($field, $value);

       $element = $page->findField($field);
       $this->getSession()->getDriver()->keyDown($element->getXpath(), '', null);
       $this->getSession()->wait(500);
       $chosenResults = $page->findAll('css', '.ui-autocomplete a');
       foreach ($chosenResults as $result) {
           if ($result->getText() == $entry) {
               $result->click();
               return;
           }
       }
       throw new \Exception(sprintf('Value "%s" not found', $entry));
   }
   """
```

Answer (score 0):

*Use this to Fill in the search box: (using the ID selector)*

```
/**
 * @Then I type :text into search box
 */
public function iTypeTextIntoSearchBox($text)
{
    $element = $this->getSession()->getPage()->findById('searchInput');
    $script  = "$('#searchInput').keypress();";
    $element->setValue($text);
    $this->getSession()->evaluateScript($script);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I can't test it - I don't even remember which project it was :) Hopefully it will help somebody still.